# How do I integrate XStream RF modules with any microcomputer (Rasp Pi, Beaglebone)?

Tags: diy, digital-modes, uhf, electronics

I have selected XStream RF modules due to their price and their range (7 miles).

I am part of a car team and hence need to transmit and receive data between the car and the ground station (follower); hence I need to know the procedure to connecting the module to our SBC (BeagleBone black) and also needed to know what I need to buy to receive this data being transmitted by the car.

Any new suggestions about the mode of communication would be appreciated (min. range: 1.5 miles).

PS: I am a beginner in radio communication so any material shared would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The xstream provides an rs232 connection controlled via AT commands. You will need to use a dialer and control it directly. If you have never worked with modems before, look up general info on the "Hayes AT command set" and have a look at the [Linux serial guide.](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/nag2/x-087-2-serial.devices.html)

That should be enough to figure it all out.